# Adding an UIView to a UITableViewCell is not showing anything

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I am new to Xcode/Swift, just started learning today. I am trying to add an empty UIView with a background color to a Stack View that is inside a TableView custom cell.

Basically my vertical stack view has only 2 elements: a label and that UIView. The label is showing fine when I run the simulator but the UIView is not visible, as if I had not added it at all in the storyboard.

I am not sure what to try here. I simply selected an UIView, dragged it into the Stack View and set its background to red. In the storyboard, it looks fine but when I run the simulator, only the label (top part of the Stack View) shows up, the red UIView is not here...

Here is a screenshot of my user interface.
You can see the red UIView is visible but not when I run the app...
However "label" is visible when I run the app.

[image: image of tableview cell]

Here is a screenshot of the simulator:
[image: screenshot]

Do you see anything wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi could you please share your simulator screenshot? one more thing you can not set stackview background color.

Comment: Sure, I have edited the message and added a screenshot of the simulator. It shows random question with the answers. All these answers are a custom value to the Label in the cell. But the UIView with red background is not showing. I am not setting the background of the stack view but the background of the UIView that I added.

Comment: it seems that the cells have a wrong hight. Did you check withe the view hierachy debugger if the view is hidden? if you dont know what I am talking about: https://medium.com/@dmytro.anokhin/overview-of-developer-tools-for-ui-debugging-122e4995f972

Comment: @Jijidev either you need to give height to your red view or add controls in that view.let me know if you required image on the same

Comment: Thanks all, using the codes proposed to me below, I can now see the view (but still can't see its background color which is weird). You were basically all right, it had to do with the height attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You issue is not clear enough, it might either be the row height, the autolayout or the stackView distribution.

Try switching the stackView distribution from "Fill Proportionally" to "Fill"

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I added another label inside the view that I couldn't see and now I can see that label inside which is good. However the background on my view is transparent (white basically as the background of the table view) even if I set backgroundColor to red. Would you know why?

Comment: the only reason i can think off the top of my head is that the views take all the space inside the stackView.

Which leads you to seeing only the label / view in your case rather than the stackView itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it saved my life. It worked after changing the distribution of UIStackview from Alignment Centre to Alignment Fill and Distribution Fill.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think there a issue of height, for testing just add

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  IndexPath!) -> CGFloat {

      return 100
}
```

And test your code again.

If its working, then read about autolayout 
You can achieve it by using autolayout. 
All the best

Comment: That helped as well when I added it to the solution proposed by Mazen, thanks. I still have an issue with the background color of that view, it is not set to red, even if I put it programmatically. Does TableView cell do anything to prevent that?

Comment: Use *Debug View Hierarchy* and check. Also update your question with code you have implemented. That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My issues got resolved after changing the distribution of UIStackview from Alignment Centre to Alignment Fill and Distribution Fill.